# reactjs - separation ui and logic with lazy-loading

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, lazy-loading, code-splitting

I want to separate my UI and logic to decrease the size of the bundle. I know I can separate the logic with the `headless components` approach or `custom hooks`, etc. but I also want to separate the logic from the bundle. I assume that I can achieve this by lazy-loading all logic and sending UI immediately.

I have created a codesandbox example to demonstrate what I want. There is a component called ui/index.js. It includes a component called `<Logic {...props} />`. The `Logic` component gets rendered when the `enableLogic` state is set to true when the UI component initially renders. The `Logic` component is lazy-loaded and returns nothing, `null`. The only purpose of the component is to render the logic.

```
const Logic = React.lazy(() =>
  import(/* webpackChunkName: "logic" */ "./logic")
);
```

My question is, having this kind of approach for simple, dummy components would be **nonsense** but sometimes, some part of the large application's logic can be **heavy**. **I wonder if, separating the logic and UI with this kind of approach can cause me any trouble?** **Is this approach used by many people? Is there any kind of library that uses the same kind of approach to separate logic and UI with lazy-loading?**

I believe that decreasing bundle size for pages with heavy logic can reduce the time that users will see pages.

**You can have a look at the implementation via codesandbox link right here.**
[**Codesandbox**](https://codesandbox.io/s/icy-dust-nhr3d?file=/src/components/ui/index.js)

Comment: Lazy loading components in that manner is a very common thing in react. The rest of your codesandbox is highly suspect - using `addEventListener/removeEventListener` is a huge WTF.

Comment: That was just a demonstration. Implementation detail on the Codesandbox means nothing actually. Just wanted to give an example of what I mean with some dummy code. You are right, I have seen and used lazy loading many times. But not in this kinda form. Sending logic later than components view layer? I want to be sure that there are no problems with this approach. https://github.com/theKashey/use-sidecar This library uses a better approach but kinda hard understanding the documentation @Adam

Comment: Everything in react is a component. Just because your component has no UI doesn't make it any less a component. If you want to split your "logic" components up from your UI components, then go ahead. In my experience, I generally like to keep "tightly coupled logic" (like interacting with elements directly in a given component) **in that component**. Decoupling them doesn't give you any benefits unless the logic is highly reusable amongst a variety of different components, in which case it could just be a hook, but then you wouldn't be able to lazy-load it.

Comment: (contd) don't overcomplicate this stuff unless you have a clear idea of the architecture you're trying to achieve. If you're just "playing around" you'll learn lots about how you can lazy load stuff, but don't use it to drive a project structure that you intend to ship.

Comment: I know I do not have a clear idea or experience of the architecture that I mention. That's why I am asking here. The problem is, sometimes some components have lots of logic developers cannot avoid. I believe by showing the view before providing logic in some cases can increase UX because we will ship less code, so less code to parse for the browser, and increase code coverage. The library I shared trying to do that and this article explain why https://dev.to/thekashey/sidecar-for-a-code-splitting-1o8g. **I do not want to ship more code that the user does not need for the initial render!**

Comment: `sometimes some components have lots of logic developers cannot avoid`. **NO** this is absolutely unequivocally 100% wrong. I see it all the time, single components that are 100s of lines long are **WRONG**. Components are composable, you can break them down into smaller components. I've been writing react for a long time and if I see a (functional) component whose body is over 40 lines in code review, I ask that it be broken down. Read rule #1 on that article you linked to. I'm not saying not to use code splitting, but make sure your architecture is reasonably clean to begin with.

Comment: Another comment of yours and I totally agree with you again. I try to do the same and always follow the atomic design and composing components.Maybe I couldn't clearly explain what I'm trying to achieve here.Even if I follow the correct patterns and approaches, I feel like I can improve the timing of the initial render and increase code coverage with the help of lazy loading. I don't want to send any code that the user doesn't need for the initial render. I'll try to implement this approach and experience my own to see if it is bad or not.Btw, thank you for your time, was a great conversation.